# i am having issue in pagination first page is working ok but second is not

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function search_tutor(){
  $config = [
    "base_url"=>base_url('search-tutor'),
            "per_page"=>2,
            "total_rows"=>$this->public_model->all_rows()
            // 'full_tag_open'=>'<ul  >',
            // 'full_tag_close'=>'</ul>',
            // 'first_tag_open'=>'<li>',
            // 'first_tag_close'=>'</li>',
            // 'last_tag_open'=>'<li>',
            // 'last_tag_close'=>'</li>',
            // 'next_tag_open'=>'<li>',
            // 'next_tag_close'=>'</li>',
            // 'prev_tag_open'=>'<li>',
            // 'prev_tag_close'=>'</prev>',
            // 'num_tag_open'=>'<li>',
            // 'num_tag_close'=>'</li>',
            // 'cur_tag_open'=>"<li><a >",
            // 'cur_tag_close'=>'</a></li>'

    ];

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data['all_tutors'] = $this->public_model->all_tutors($config['per_page'],$page);

  $data['cities'] = $this->admin_model->cities();
  $data['degree_levels'] = $this->admin_model->degree_levels();
  $data['subjects'] = $this->public_model->all_subjects();
  $this->load->view('public_template/search_header');
  $this->load->view('public_template/navbar');enter code here
  $this->load->view('public/search_tutor',$data);
  $this->load->view('public_template/footer_links');
  $this->load->view('public_template/search_footer',$data);
}
```

this is function in which i'm defining pagination . so first page is wokring ok but when i click on 2 in pagination display scrambles like some css files are or attached. i think it is because i'm doing custom routing. because i have worked on pagination but then i hadn't defined routes so can anybody help me with this.
display is as expected when url is http://localhost/tutor/search-tutor but when it changes to http://localhost/tutor/search-tutor/ or http://localhost/tutor/search-tutor/2 it is not as expected to be. 
and i have defined routes as 
$route['search-tutor'] = 'public_controller/search_tutor';
i' have tried following also
$route['search-tutor/(:num)'] = 'public_controller/search_tutor/$1';
but result is same
thanks in advance.

Comment: is "http://localhost/tutor/search-tutor/2 " hitting ur controller or producing 404?

Comment: its hitting controller but display is scrambled. like its just showing html

Comment: did u try printing of $this->uri->segment(2) ?

Comment: yes i tried. when page is opened it's 1 when i click on 2 in pagination it becomes 2